Quitting PhD and graduating with an M. Phil
I could really use some advice right now. A few months ago I got out of a Ph.D and decided to submit for an M. Phil after 2 years in an incredibly damaging and hostile environment in a UK University.
I am an international student and I am currently in the submission pending period of my M. Phil thesis (I am submitting a thesis with 5 chapters).
I have tried to apply for various other PhD projects that intrest me after having spoken to numerous PIs about my situation, they seemed to understand, but I haven't been able to make it through the DTPs shortlisting. Which I think is understandable because they must view me as a high-risk candidate as a quit my previous PhD.
I have also tried to apply for RA positions but to no avail. I'm extremely anxious and am incredibly stressed out if I'll ever make it out of this situation. I'm starting to feel extremely hopeless. Any advice/ help will be greatly appreciated. Should I try to do lab placements in my area of interest?
Thanks a lot!

Also don't forget that the majority of people do not stay in academia, even if they finish the PhD. If it turns out you don't have an option to finish it that you like, you'll probably find a better paying job outside of academia than if you had stayed.

Everyone's path through life is different. I don't think a question as broad as "What should I do in life now?" is going to yield much useful material.

In what area of science are you working? Are you planning to read for PhD in the UK only, or are you also considering the US?

Not your question, but make sure to check your visa restrictions.  In the UK you usually cannot move to another university on the same student visa (you would need to go back to your home country and apply for a new visa). This could be a significant restriction on your options. There are very few, if any, exceptions...

(1) Quitting PhD and getting a Master's degree is very common; you have nothing to worry about if this would have any negative impacts on you. (2) You don't have to mention you quit from your PhD program when applying for PhD positions, you don't need to say anything about it. (3) I don't know UK student visa policy. If UK doesn't work, why not try other countries? (4) Working in a hostile environment eventually hurts you.

Only a person who has never experienced any difficulty could be condescending and not relate to your experiene. Many of us have been there or had friends experience hostile environments. Of course you would be extremely stressed.
You made a great decision to salvage your work and graduate with a M. Phil. Focus on the positives. I wouldn't hide that you came out of a very negative environment, chances are that group is already known for it. Just don't focus on it, it does not define you, just state it as a reason to move on and find something better. The fact that you got out, still achieved M. Phil. and show such dedication to the fild that you are wiling to go on, says a lot. Focus on your abilities and your persistence to pursue this work. Such environments are far more common than you think, unfortunately. Check on GlassDoor, maybe someone already described it as a toxic place, and maybe leave a revierw there as well to help others.
Hang in there and keep trying, present yourself as a determined person who does not stop because of such setbacks.

Why not stop sharing your 'sad' story and focus on preparing a high-quality research proposal for your future study? You don't need to tell everyone the 'truth' to prove that you didn't do anything wrong. Strong person never struggles with the past. Can you guarantee that you won't quit again? This is the question in the other PI's mind. No one wants to take that risk. If what you care the most is your research work but not the honour that a PhD degree will bring to you and your family, you won't suffer any more.

Is professional antagonist the career path you chose, or is it just a natural talent?
